# How can I set the timeout and the life of a session in android

Tags: android, session

I know about session in `php` well. For example its default lifetime in `php` is 24 min. Also I searched about the session for android in internet and I found tutorials about Shared Preferences. But in all of this tutorials the files of the `sessions` are produced always.

Comment: well a service with a timer can make your game

Comment: Didn't got u..try to make your question clear